# Exercise using Nakayama Lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a commutative unitary ring, $I$ an ideal contained in the Jacobson radical of $A$; let $M$ be an $A$-module and $N$ a finitely generated $A$-module, and let $u: M \to N$ be a homomorphism.
>   If the induced homomorphism $\bar u: M/ IM\to N/IN$ is surjective, then $u$ is surjective.

Some approaches that may be used:

1) If $M/ IM = 0$ then by Nakayama Lemma $M=0$. Now if we can show somehow that $(N/u(M))/I(N/u(M))=0$ then we are done. Since $N/u(M)=0 \implies u(M)=N$.

To use the Nakayama Lemma we need N to be finitely generated and I to be inside the Jacobson radical both of which are satisfied.

Now we need to use the surjectivity of the induced map and some sort of embedding to show that $(N/u(M))/I(N/u(M))=0$, but I cannot find a proper well-defined embedding using the surjectivity of the induced map. Any other approach would be really helpful too.

Comment: The image of $\bar u$ is $(u(M)+IN)/IN$. Since it is surjective we must have $u(M)+IN=N$. Now use Nakayama.

Comment: I can't prove that The image of $\bar u$ is (u(M)+IN)/IN